# Dropping unnecessary indexes - effect on query plans in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, indexing, database-performance

Below is a portion of the index mess we have on a 2MM record table (SQL Server 2005). Clearly there are opportunities to pear them down.  This table has 16 indexes altogether, including a clustered PK on `[MemberID], [RegistryID],[end_date]`, but I only listed the ones that seem to be candidates for consolidation.

I'm tempted to just drop `[ix_IndexName7]` for example, because it's superfluous. But according to `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` it seems to be in some query plan or another.

This is my question.  Let's say I drop `[ix_IndexName7]` or `[ix_IndexName30]` (which I think is covered by `[idxMemberRegistry1]`). When a query plan tries to find `[ix_IndexName7]` and can't, will the optimizer magically incorporate one of the other indexes whose first column is `[MemberID]`? Or will I have to find whatever SPs/views/functions use that table and recompile them (which would suck because there are probably a junkload).  Or something else?

I hope this question is clear.  I'd appreciate any input!

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_RegistryID] ON [dbo].[Member_Registry] ([RegistryId], [end_date], [MemberId])
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_MemberID] ON [dbo].[Member_Registry] ([MemberId], [RegistryId], [end_date]) INCLUDE ([Due_Date])
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_IndexName7] ON [dbo].[Member_Registry] ([end_date]) INCLUDE ([MemberId])
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_IndexName11] ON [dbo].[Member_Registry] ([end_date]) INCLUDE ([MemberId], [RegistryId])
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_IndexName16] ON [dbo].[Member_Registry] ([end_date]) INCLUDE ([ContinuousEnrol], [MemberId], [RegistryId])
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_IndexName30] ON [dbo].[Member_Registry] ([end_date]) INCLUDE ([MemberId], [P4P_Patient], [RegistryId])
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_IndexName29] ON [dbo].[Member_Registry] ([end_date], [ContinuousEnrol]) INCLUDE ([MemberId], [RegistryId])
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idxMemberRegistry1] ON [dbo].[Member_Registry] ([end_date], [MemberId], [RegistryId]) INCLUDE ([COL_D2yr], [ContinuousEnrol], [P4P_AAB], [P4P_ACE], [P4P_CERVICAL], [P4P_Chlamydia], [P4P_COL], [P4P_DGX], [P4P_DIU], [P4P_MAMMO], [P4P_Patient], [start_date])
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_AllPatients] ON [dbo].[Member_Registry] ([MemberId], [RegistryId], [end_date]) INCLUDE ([EXCLUSION_STATUS], [P4P_Patient])
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_Exclusion_Status] ON [dbo].[Member_Registry] ([MemberId], [RegistryId], [EXCLUSION_STATUS])
```

Comment: My advice:  Run query 4 and 5 from Glenn's super cool list.......... http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/five-dmv-queries-that-will-make-you-a-superhero-in-2011/

Comment: Keep in mind that part of balanced performance is the cost of inserting/updating/deleting.  Removing some indexes that greatly speed rarely used queries, e.g year-end reports, may have a worthwhile payback in improved performance on writes.  Falling back from index 7 to 11 may have minimal impact on reads, but simplifies writes.  It all depends on _your_ data and _your_ workload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you drop some index and run the query again, it will recompile a new execution plan, maybe some of the remaining indexes will be used, maybe not. Is a matter of testing and see wich action will help the most or on the contrary, will ruin all the performance.

These scripts sure will come handy to make a decision when talking about indexes:

- [sp_BlitzIndex](http://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/) also from @Brent Ozar
- [sp_IndexAnalysis](http://www.jasonstrate.com/2013/03/index-analysis-march-update/) from Jason Strate
- Ola Hallengren [SQL Server Index and Statistics Maintenance](http://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html)

They all together give plenty of information about current status of you indexes, duplicates, unused, statistics, wait states, I/O uses, and much more. Based on that information you can do a more accurrate analysis and select the best option.

Comment: Thank you all very much! I will use everyone's advice. Unfortunately, this database is a total disaster area with hundreds of obsolete objects and this is a commonly referenced table, but I'll test as thoroughly as my sanity allows. To your point, @HABO, I learned what the `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_updates` column means and will definitely incorporate it into my decision making. Plus, the size vs. usage tradeoff is probably relevant given that we've got about 20GB left on this server (*sigh*).

Comment: Glad we can help Anna. Don't forget to check the answer that was useful for you as the correct answer, so other know where to look when passing by.

Answer (score 0):

Query Plans are invalidated when certain kinds of changes happen to their sources.  This would include dropping any indexes that it is using.  Invalidated query plans are not used.

Failing to find a valid matching query plan in the cache, a pending query would just make a new one...